# two versions of ubuntu on my computer but i want to access files from the other one on the new one

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery

I was trying to upgrade my ubuntu 13.04 and i shut it off before it finishes and then it wouldn't boot. Not knowing what to do, i decided to reinstall it, but since i was afraid of losing my files from the previous one, i installed 12.10 side to side. now i need my files from the previous one but that one still doesn't boot. and the new one is empty. Can someone please help me find a way to access my files from the previous version? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Well it's simple**

You applied that much brain to install Ubuntu, should have thought little more.

Ubuntu is often used as rescue disk. Since you are installing ubuntu it means that you've Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB. Use that one to boot Ubuntu. This time select option  **Use Ubuntu** not the option `Install Ubuntu`.

Once Ubuntu booted you can access your files from the previous install (hope you didn't format and installed another Ubuntu on the same partition).

Reply if you need further assistance..